# What is the best time to book the car train to Livorno?

Tags: budget, trains, automobiles, bookings, livorno

I have been meaning to take the car train to [Livorno](http://www.seat61.com/Motorail.htm#Auto%20Slaap%20Trein). I always seem to start to late. Should I book now for next summer, or will the fee drop at some stage between now and then?

Comment: I don't know if it makes a difference, but where will you be travelling from?

Comment: @MarkMayo The autotrain mentioned has one start and one endpoint

Comment: fair enough, I wasn't sure and just wanted to make sure it was covered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no stages, early booking is usually cheaper, as you will get your place. If you want to press price down, select shared accommodation, but you lose the privacy. You can pick some special offer if is available. Best guide I ever found for this is on [The Man in Seat Sixty-One website](http://www.seat61.com/Motorail.htm#.UsFz3vhEXVM) Follow the links mentioned to discover/monitor if there is a special offer suitable for you. It does not look so at the moment.